# Customizing FrameTicks in DistributionChart

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and fixed in 13.2.0 or earlier**

---

So I have been fighting with this for a while. I'm trying to get custom frame ticks on both the left and right side of a `DistributionChart`. It's not going very well. It just keeps throwing errors saying tick position needs to be a number. Which in my code it is. Here is an example:

```
With[
 {fps = {120, 60, 50, 40, 30, 25, 20, 15, 10}},
 DistributionChart[
  RandomVariate[SkewNormalDistribution[##], 100] & @@@ {{20, 13, 5}, {30, 12, 10}},
  ChartLabels -> {1, 2},
  PlotRange -> {0, 70},
  GridLines -> {None, N@Table[1/i*1000, {i, fps}]},
  FrameTicks -> {
   {
     Table[{N[1/i*1000], NumberForm[N[1/i*1000], 3]}, {i, fps}],(*Left*)
     Table[{1/i*1000, i}, {i, fps}] (*Right*)
   },
   {
     None,(*Bottom*)
     None (*Top*)
   }
  }
 ]
]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It seems there is a bug in there. Try `AbsoluteOptions@
 DistributionChart[RandomReal[BetaDistribution[2, 1/4], {6, 100}]]`

Comment: This example from the documentation for `DistributionChart` also has a problem with Ticks: `DistributionChart[data, ChartLabels -> {"a", "b", "c"}]
AbsoluteOptions[%]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be a bug here as even

```
DistributionChart[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 1, 2, 3}}, FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {None, None}}]
```

yields an error, but you can work around it as follows:

```
With[{fps = {120, 60, 50, 40, 30, 25, 20, 15, 10}}, 
 DistributionChart[
   RandomVariate[SkewNormalDistribution[##], 100] & @@@ {{20, 13, 5}, {30, 12, 10}}, 
   ChartLabels -> {1, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 70}, 
   GridLines -> {None, N@Table[1/i*1000, {i, fps}]}
 ] /. 
  Rule[FrameTicks, __] -> 
   Rule[FrameTicks, {{Table[{N[1/i*1000],NumberForm[N[1/i*1000], 3]}, {i, fps}],(*Left*)
      Table[{1/i*1000, i}, {i, fps}] (*Right*)}, {None,(*Bottom*) None (*Top*)}}]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you. Your workaround works perfectly. `DistributionChart` seems quite buggy. This is not the first bug in it I've run in to.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been resolved in the latest -`13.2.0`- version or earlier

The code from the OP

```
With[{fps = {120, 60, 50, 40, 30, 25, 20, 15, 10}}, 
 DistributionChart[
  RandomVariate[SkewNormalDistribution[##], 100] & @@@ {{20, 13, 
     5}, {30, 12, 10}}, ChartLabels -> {1, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 70}, 
  GridLines -> {None, N@Table[1/i*1000, {i, fps}]}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Table[{N[1/i*1000], NumberForm[N[1/i*1000], 3]}, {i,
        fps}],(*Left*)
     Table[{1/i*1000, i}, {i, fps}] (*Right*)}, {None,(*Bottom*)
     None (*Top*)}}]]
```

Screenshot for completeness

> [image: screen]