# Custom ticks in distribution chart

Tags: plotting

I am trying to just get simple logarithmic ticks to the distribution chart, and failing... It is unhappy with any `FrameTicks` format I try (sparing `-> Automatic`). What am I doing wrong?

```
DistributionChart[
  Log[RandomReal[ExponentialDistribution[100], 50]], 
  Frame -> True, ChartStyle -> LightBlue, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{{Log[0.001], "0.001"}, {Log[0.01],"0.01"}}, None}, {None, None}},
  ChartElementFunction -> "HistogramDensity",
  ChartLabels -> {"s "}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}]
```

Comment: Would [that](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6W6d.png) fit you?

Comment: Yes I've seen this - but it is a rather complicated set of rules that seems like a heavy overkill for the problem (and I failed to adapt it). Interestingly, using Show[] and specifying FrameTicks inside Show[D-chart, FrameTicks-> blabla] somewhat works after modifying the label as well; yet it is a pain as I have a large array of charts, where most work just fine without the need for the log scale.

Comment: Check the image in my second comment to see if it fits you

Comment: This is the workaround using Show, and modifying the Label. I guess it will do..:                            Show[DistributionChart[
  Log[RandomReal[ExponentialDistribution[100], 50]], 
  FrameLabel -> {"s ", ""}, 
  ChartElementFunction -> "HistogramDensity", 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}], 
 FrameTicks -> {{{{Log[0.001], "0.001"}, {Log[0.01], "0.01"}}, 
    None}, {None, None}}]

Comment: OOPS sorry - yes. How did you get it?

Comment: I will post an answer soon :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Customizing FrameTicks in DistributionChart](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11702/1356) here is what you can do:

```
DistributionChart[Log[RandomReal[ExponentialDistribution[100], 50]], 
  Frame -> True, ChartStyle -> LightBlue, 
  ChartElementFunction -> "HistogramDensity", FrameLabel -> {"s "}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}] /. 
Rule[FrameTicks, __] -> 
  Rule[FrameTicks, {{{{Log[0.001], "0.001"}, {Log[0.01], "0.01"}}, None}, {None, None }}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Yep that works! Thanks! Though I guess the mechanism is the same like in Show[Dchart, CustomLabelSpecification] - also here one needs to change the ChartLabels to FrameLabel -> {"s "}.

Comment: @Jitka Ooops, correct. Edited :)

Comment: Where, where? :) It seems like a minor nuisance, yet I;ve got charts where there is more than one distribution in one D-chart, and then it works not with the FrameLabel... Many thanks, anyway! I hope the artistic editors will be somewhat tolerant, given this is just in supplementary info.. :)

Comment: Thanks. It seems the refresh did not work earlier on.